# To show absolute continuity of measures.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, absolute-continuity, radon-nikodym

Let $\delta_x$ denote the measure defined by

$$\delta_x(E)=\begin{cases} 
      1, & x\in E \\
      0, & x\not\in E \\
   \end{cases}
$$

Let $\mu:=m+\delta_0+\delta_1$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\lambda$ be a signed Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any continuously differentiable, compactly supported function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)d\lambda(x)=\int_0^1f'(x)x^2dm(x)$$

I need to show that $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and find its Radon-Nikodym derivative.

My attempt: If $\mu(E)=0$, then $m(E)=0$ and $0,1\not\in E$. I know I need to show that $\lambda(E)=0$. All I have is the following and I can't seem to proceed.

$$\lambda(E)=\int \chi_E d\lambda$$

Clearly $\chi_E$ is not continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Where do I go from here? Hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use integration by parts on the right side. You can now guess what the R-N derivative should be. The answer is $\frac {d\lambda} {d\mu}=g$ where $g(x)=-2x$ for $0 <x<1$, $g(1)=1$ and $g(0)=0$. To show that this works you have to use the well known fact that if $\int fd\tau =\int f d\mu$ for all continuously differentiable $f$ with compact support and $\tau \{0\}=\mu \{0\}$, $\tau \{1\}=\mu \{1\}$ then $\tau =\mu$.

[Some details added in my comment below].

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm still unable to see absolute continuity of $\lambda$ with respect to $\mu$. How do I see that? Also, could you please prescribe a reference to the fact you've alluded to?

Comment: @tangentbundle $\int fd\lambda=f(1)-2\int_0^{1} xf(x)dm(x)$. Continuously differentiable functions with compact support are dense in $L^{1} (\lambda+m)$. See Rudin's RCA for a proof. It follows that above equation holds for all $f \in L^{1} (\lambda+m)$. This proves absolute continuity by taking $f$ to be a characterisitic function of  a Borel set.